# EXCEL 2010 Check if sub string value in cell match with other string from range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am stuck with this one from hours.

I have range with cells with string values:

> A1 text1
>
> A2 text2
>
> An text3

And other column with other string values like:

> B1 text1sampletext
>
> B2 text2sampletext
>
> B3 text3sampletext
>
> B4 text1sampletext
>
> B5 text1sampletext

I have to check if text in column A is sub string of text in column B. If it is, to set in column C the text from column A.

Like this:

> B1 text1sampletext - C1 text1
>
> B2 text2sampletext - C1 text2
>
> B3 text3sampletext - C1 text3
>
> B4 text1sampletext - C1 text1
>
> B5 text1sampletext - C1 text1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work in Excel 2010 and doesn't require "array entry"

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(A$1:A$3,B1),A$1:A$3),"not found")`

`FIND` is case-sensitive, if you don't want the formula to be case-sensitive replace `FIND` wiith `SEARCH`

Assumes that A1:A3 doesn't contain blanks

Answer (score 1):

No doubt Barry will embarrass me

But something like this in C1 and copied down will work for xl07 and xl10

Press [ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)[shift](/questions/tagged/shift)[enter](/questions/tagged/enter)
together to enter this as an array formula

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$3,MATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A$1:A$3,B1))),0)),"not found")`

for all xl versions
again with Press [ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)[shift](/questions/tagged/shift)[enter](/questions/tagged/enter)
`=IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A$1:A$3,B1))),0))),INDEX(A$1:A$3,MATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A$1:A$3,B1))),0)),"not found")`

Comment: I was not able to use your code. The first give me errors, i try to fix it, but still no working. The second gives me only "not found". Could assist to find the problem?

Comment: the second argument is missing in the first formula in the `ISERROR` formula inside the `MATCH`. I am looking for an answer to make it work

Comment: the second formula worked OK for me but 1st formula needs a closing parenthesis to work, suggested edit to that effect

Comment: @barryhoudini thx, I see you have made the update

Answer (score 1):

I didn't manage for now to make Dave (brettdj)'s solution working.

Here is a UDF that would work:

```
Function copyText(rSubstr As Range, rText As Range)
'Check if any of the cell value from rSubstr exists in rText
Dim c As Range

If rText.Count > 1 Then Exit Function

For Each c In rSubstr
    If InStr(1, rText.Value, c.Value) > 0 Then
        copyText = c.Value
        Exit Function
    End If
Next c
End Function
```

Simply use this function in your worksheet:

```
=copyText($A$1:$A$3;B1)
```